# Detect TouchesEnded after changing the superview of the target

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

In iOS I am dragging a UIView between two parent UIViews.  I am using UIPanGestureRecognizer to manage the dragging.  While the dragging is still going on I switch the parent for the view being dragged by using:

```
- (IBAction)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    ...
    [viewBeingDragged removeFromSuperview];
    UIView* page2 = [self.view viewWithTag:pageTag];
    [page2 addSubview:viewBeingDragged];
    // Now scroll page 2 into view
    [pageContainerScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(xcoord, 0) animated:YES];
    ...
```

This seems to terminate the panning events.  My finger however is still 'down'.  At this point how can I detect my finger lifting up?  I've tried a separate UITapGestureRecognizer which fires fine if panning is not occurring, but which does not fire if panning has started.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        ...
    }

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
    recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanFrom:)];        
    [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```

And

```
-(void)handlePanFrom:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    if ( [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded )
    {
        NSLog(@"Ended");
    }
}
```

You can find all the states [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161047/changing-superview-breaks-uipangesturerecognizer). You just need to remove the line: `[viewBeingDragged removeFromSuperview];`.

A UIView can only have one superview, so when you call `[page2 addSubview:viewBeingDragged]` the `viewBeingDragged` UIView will first be removed from its current superview.